# Is there a function that returns the number of characters in BigNumber.js?

Tags: javascript, digits, bignum, bignumber.js

I know about [decimalPlaces](https://mikemcl.github.io/bignumber.js/#dp):

```js
const number = new BigNumber(100.5254);
number.decimalPlaces(); // 4
```

And [precision](https://mikemcl.github.io/bignumber.js/#sd):

```js
const number = new BigNumber(100.5254);
number.precision(); // 7
```

But I couldn't find any function that returns only the number of characteristics. That is, in this example, 3 ("1", "0" and "0").

Is there something for this?

Comment: There are no leading or trailing zeros, so the isn't the number of significant digits *actually* 7? If the calculation being performed isn't meant to be accurate to 7 significant digits, then that's something that should be addressed manually elsewhere (it's not something that a plain method could determine, unless you include a statistics package of some kind and give it context...)

Comment: how  about precision() - decimalPlaces() ?

Comment: The `.sd()` method returns the number of significant digits, which is 7 in your example. (Hint: it's an alias for `precision`).

Comment: Sorry all, I updated the question. I am looking for the number of "characteristics" - the digits before the dot.

Comment: Do the math : 3 = 7 - 4 you have all you needed

Comment: @ThanhTrung Yeah I did that, but I use it in my places so I would've avoided creating my own var for this, if possible. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there isn't one, as of Nov 2019 at least, but you can subtract the decimal places from the total precision to get the digits before the dot:

```js
const number = new BigNumber(100.5254);
const digitsBeforeDot = number.precision(true) - number.decimalPlaces();
// prints 3
```

Note that:

> If `d` (the first parameter of the `precision` function) is true then any trailing zeros of the integer part of a number are counted as significant digits, otherwise they are not.

See the docs:

- [decimalPlaces()](https://mikemcl.github.io/bignumber.js/#dp)
- [precision()](https://mikemcl.github.io/bignumber.js/#sd)